# How do I attach certificates to the my local Rest API in order to connect to Postgres database in Google Cloud?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, vert.x, quarkus

I am trying to connect to my postgres db with my certificates from GCP, on my REST-API. This does work locally with a local db and local client.

But I am now putting it on the cloud and therefore need to connect with ssl certificates. I can use kubernetes secrets if that is possible, but I do not know how. I have authorized my Public IP in the Cloud.
See the Images for a better understanding. 
[Screenshot of Application.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC25Q.jpg)
[Screenshot of cert and pem files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjkNg.png)

Comment: Are you trying to connect from GCE instance or from the local environment?

Comment: I want to connect the Rest API Pod in my GCP cluster to the Postgresql instance in my GCP that is my priority. So yes from GCE instance you can say.

Comment: You can use internal IP to connect from within GCP without SSL. Otherwise I spent a little bit of time and looks like `quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://$IP:5432/postgres?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&sslcert=client-cert.pem&sslkey=client-key.pem&sslrootcert=server-ca.pem` this raises exception but you need to pass key provider which should probably occur before setup. Probably it's not implemented on Quarkus side

Comment: What error are you gettting?

Comment: So open up the Private IP connection in the SQL settings first and then change the application.properties and create a new build to upload to the pod you mean? @DmytroChaban

Comment: @jjanes I get a Connection Timeout, but I think I need to connect with the certificates, but I dont know how to add them securly in to the Rest Api POD

Comment: You won't know if the certs are working until you fix the timeout, which is probably a firewall issue.

Comment: @jjanes `Trust options must be specified under verify-full or verify-ca sslmode`. If I set sslmode to required I get `SSL handshake failed`, which is probably because of missing certs

Comment: Can you check the Postgresql server's log file for the message it reports?  Sometimes it  is more useful than the client's error report.

Comment: @IlhamJilani Yes, this link might help https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine basically ip would be a private ip and credentials would be passed as a secret(or you can try hardcode them firstly to check if it'll work and then pass as a secret

Comment: @jjanes org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: $IP:5432

Comment: I changed to private IP now, now I get this: Caused by: io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "10.60.2.26", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Does this mean I have to put in the certificates, but how?